# Plot density/proportion histograms with hue parameter in seaborn jointplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram, jointplot

Is there a way to specify both hue and have the marginal histograms be plotted with stat=density ? It seems I can have one or the other -- it will graph either without the `hue` kwa or without `stat='density'`, but it errors out when I include both parameters.

Here is some example code:

```
penguins=sns.load_dataset('penguins')
sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue='species',marginal_kws=dict(color='r',stat='density'))
```

And here is the error:

```
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-e8d515eeeab0> in <module>
----> 1 sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue='species',marginal_kws=dict(color='r',stat='density'))

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in _update_property(self, k, v)
    999                 func = getattr(self, 'set_' + k, None)
   1000                 if not callable(func):
-> 1001                     raise AttributeError('{!r} object has no property {!r}'
   1002                                          .format(type(self).__name__, k))
   1003                 return func(v)

AttributeError: 'PolyCollection' object has no property 'stat'`
```

Thanks!

I can get a jointplot with two colors which are designated by a categorical value in my dataframe. However, I would like for the marginal histograms to be plotted by density as specified in `histplot` but not absolute value, because one of the categories has many more entries than the other. I cannot get both `hue` and `stat=density` without the code erroring out as above.

Comment: With `hue`, you get density curves using `kdeplot` on the marginal axes, so not `histplot`.

Comment: Maybe in two steps: `g = sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue='species')` and `g.plot_marginals(sns.histplot, stat='density')`

Comment: What you want to accomplish is a little confusing — you're using `hue` but also passing `marginal_kws(color="r")`. Are you expecting to get one histogram (i.e., disabling `hue` for the marginal plots) or three red histograms?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get what I needed by modifying kdeplot instead of histplot. kdeplot did what I needed, at least for now.